# Return 2 values in lambda function python

Tags: python, networkx

I am working with graphs using networkx. I want to achieve the longest path based on weight on the edges. So far the code looks like :

```
df = pd.read_csv('values.csv')

Graphtype = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Destination', edge_attr='value',create_using=Graphtype) 

def get_weight(G, path):
    total = 0
    for u, v in zip(path[:-1], path[1:]):
        total += G.get_edge_data(u,v)[0]['value']
    return total



longest_path = max((path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 'a', 'd')),
                    key=lambda path: get_weight(G,path))
```

The output returns me the longest path to achieve the same. Now I also want to return the weight of the path that is returned.

I can do `weight_max = get_weight(G,longest_path)` to get the weight as well.

Is there any way to return both the path and the weight in the single lambda function itself or any other way.

Thanks

Comment: You can't return two values using lambda

Comment: @YogeshMhaskule Thank you for your answer, is there any other way that it can be achieved ?

Comment: You most certainly *can* return multiple values with a lambda.

Comment: My first thought is to return a list or tuple containing the values.

Comment: @FedericoS can you post a method of achieving the same?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Any pointers would be appreciated. Could you provide some explaination. Thanks

Comment: I just posted an answer. Note that when you return multiple values with any function, it *is* effectively a tuple, so returning a tuple is equivalent.

Comment: what exactly is in the file `values.csv`?

Comment: @MEdwin Thats where I am creating the graph.

Answer (score 5):

You can return multiple values with a lambda by explicitly wrapping these in parentheses:

```py
>>> invert = lambda x, y: (y, x)
>>> invert(1, 2)
(2, 1)
```

Note that assignment to lambdas is nonsensical, I only did it above for demonstration purposes.

This means that, in your code, you could do:

```py
# ...
longest_path = max((path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 'a', 'd')),
                    key=lambda path: (get_weight(G,path), path))
# ...
```

If my understanding of what you need it to is correct. If not, hopefully you can generalise the concept easily enough.

Comment: Multiple returns for any given function *are* a tuple. I encourage you to compare the output of `type()` on my lambda above versus a named function with `return y, x`.

Comment: @YogeshMhaskule the question is "Is there any way..." and not "individually". Please re-read the question.

Comment: Upvoted for the clarity and excellence of the answer.

Comment: @FedericoS Thank you for explaining this. However, for the code which you shared, I am already getting the path based on the maximum weight. So the get_weight() returns the weight and the path that has maximum value is selected and returned. Now, I also want to return the weight of the path that is returned. Not sure your code would do the same. anyways I got the concept of what you are trying to say. Thank you so much for the same.

Comment: well done. I agree with this answer. it is good to show any practical solutions and then it is left for the questioner to check if solves the problem.